# Installed a package in Python but cannot import it

Tags: python, windows, installation, setup.py

I have definitely installed this package locally, called `app`. However, I am not able to run a Python file where it imports this package and get the `ModuleNotFound` error.

```
PS C:\clippd\clippd-meta-functions\app> python -m pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/clippd/clippd-meta-functions/app
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: app
  Attempting uninstall: app
    Found existing installation: app 0.1.0
    Uninstalling app-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled app-0.1.0
  Running setup.py develop for app
Successfully installed app-0.1.0
PS C:\clippd\clippd-meta-functions\app> & C:/Users/rijul/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/clippd/clippd-meta-functions/app/gamification/complete_flow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\clippd\clippd-meta-functions\app\gamification\complete_flow.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app.gamification.streaks.intra_round.ir_class import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Comment: Not a powershell user... but that's a different python path, so different python exe?

Answer (score 0):

Ummmm, I think you have different version python

Comment: So what version of python should you recommend - currently I am using 3.10.7 64-bit (microsoft store)